# Combining concepts in C++ via parameter

Tags: c++, templates

Seems difficult to combine C++ concepts in a way where they can be used as constraint on some new template, due to concept templates not being fully treated as class templates (just kind of).

Actually, what I want todo WORKS on Visual Studio compilers, but not clang/g++.

[Compiler Explorer Illustration](https://godbolt.org/z/MT81Tc3Tf)

Background

```
template <typename ITERABLE, typename OF_T>
concept IIterable = ranges::range<ITERABLE> and is_convertible_v<ranges::range_value_t<ITERABLE>, OF_T>;
static_assert (IIterable<vector<int>, int>);
static_assert (IIterable<vector<long int>, int>);
static_assert (IIterable<vector<int>, long int>);
static_assert (not IIterable<vector<string>, int>);  // legit 'iterable' but cannot convert string to int
```

Then used as a constraint on some other template (e.g. constructor arg for container).

```
template <typename T>
struct Collection { ...
template <IIterable<T> ITERABLE_OF_ADDABLE>
Collection (ITERABLE_OF_ADDABLE&& src)
```

That all works fine on all compilers I've tested. But now I wish to generalize concept IIterable, so I have a generic constraint on the elements of the input iterable

```
// 'range + some other constraint'
template <typename ITERABLE, template <typename> typename ITEM_PREDICATE>
concept IIterableWith = ranges::range<ITERABLE> and ITEM_PREDICATE<ranges::range_value_t<ITERABLE>>::value;
```

So far so good. Now it gets a LITTLE tricker. How do I define the 'constaint' on my elements. I'd LIKE to use the native C++ concept 'currying' concepts, and just be able to pass in convertible_to

```
template <typename ITERABLE, typename OF_T>
concept IIterable1 = IIterableWith<ITERABLE, convertible_to<OF_T>>;
```

But the template type currying doesn't appear to work with any compiler in this context. No problem. I can write it myself.

```
template <typename T>
struct IsAddableOfT {
    // extra confusing level of struct/tests due to fact that type currying only works on concepts
    // not class templates, and cannot just write two 'template' statements in a row for an alias template - must break up like this.
    template <typename POTENTIALLY_ADDABLE_T>
    using Test = is_convertible<POTENTIALLY_ADDABLE_T, T>;
};
```

This too works FINE on any compiler I choose (so far).

NOW the problem!

```
template <typename ITERABLE, typename OF_T>
concept IIterable = IIterableWith<ITERABLE, typename IsAddableOfT<OF_T>::Test>;
```

This works FINE on visual studio compiler (see above compiler explorer link) - but fails on gcc and clang (note typename before IsAddableOfT required to work with visual studio and tried with template and without for clang/gcc: still no luck).

```
type/value mismatch at argument 2 in template parameter list for 'template<class ITERABLE, template<class> class ITEM_PREDICATE> concept IIterableWith
```

NOTE - an ELEGANT solution to this would be if the there existed a CONCEPT (not a type trait) something like:

```
 template <concept <typename>A, concept <typename>B>
 concept conjunction = A && B
```

Comment: While you can't constrain a concept, you could constrain a type trait and use that in a concept.

Comment: no error with clang here https://godbolt.org/z/bj8TPhzG8

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai you have to change which line is commented out - 23/24 - to reproduce the problem or not (with clang/gcc - works either way with msvc).

Comment: you should post one piece of code as [mcve] or at least provide the godbolt link to the compiler error with clang.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai - https://godbolt.org/z/d7o8Wo3T3

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai Didn't post MINIMAL example, because I thought it important to motivate WHY. This is not a COMPILER BUG REPORT. Its a language design choice question (at least it might be - not sure yet).

Comment: I have no idea what @463035818_is_not_an_ai and the others are talking about. Your code is minimal and reproducible, and your code is certainly possible to actually write.

Comment: You write "WORKS on Visual Studio compilers, but not clang/g++." and then "Compiler Explorer Illustration" but the godbolt is not illustrating that it does not work with clang/g++. Thats all I am saying. I am not saying that this question cannot be answered because it lacks details. I misunderstood what you wrote and I think it would be easy to fix by actually making the godbolt link illustrate what you write it would illustrate. Peace :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the `template` disambiguator, not `typename`, because `IsAddableOfT::Test` is not a type, but a template.
The following code compiles with GCC 13 `-std=c++20`:

```cpp
#include <concepts>
#include <type_traits>
#include <ranges>
#include <array>

template <typename ITERABLE, template <typename> typename ITEM_PREDICATE>
concept IIterableWith = std::ranges::range<ITERABLE>
                    and ITEM_PREDICATE<std::ranges::range_value_t<ITERABLE>>::value;

// note: IsConvertibleTo seems like a more appropriate name, given how
//       it is implemented.
//       (it doesn't have anything to do with the plus operator)
template <typename TO>
struct IsConvertibleTo {
    template <typename FROM>
    using Test = std::is_convertible<FROM, TO>;
};

// 'template' disambiguator necessary here because Test is dependent on OF_T here.
// The compiler cannot know what the meaning of Test is without it, and it's
// not a type.
template <typename ITERABLE, typename OF_T>
concept IIterable = IIterableWith<ITERABLE, IsConvertibleTo<OF_T>::template Test>;

// Template disambiguator unnecessary here, because the compiler knows the
// definition of IsConvertibleTo<int> and thus knows what ::Test means.
static_assert(IIterableWith<std::array<int, 10>, IsConvertibleTo<int>::Test>);
```

*See [live example on Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/WYeq8MTEf)*

*Note: using the `template` disambiguator in this way is deprecated since C++23, but necessary in C++20*.

Comment: THANK YOU for the CLEAR, CORRECT, HELPFUL and PROMPT response.

Comment: My only struggle is because there were TWO very good responses and I need to pick between them ;-). Yours has less color, but is more direct, to the point, and concise, so I will probably choose it.

Comment: You say "disambiguator needed because"... but the other poster says that its DEPRECATED in C++23, so maybe needed for now, but not necessarily exactly cuz ambiguous (if he's right).

Comment: You are RIGHT about the name change - IsConvertibleTo  - naming made sense in the ORIGINAL context my example came from, but here you are certainly right. And maybe your name is better for my original context.

Comment: @lewis it's deprecated in C++23 because it's unnecessary in C++23. It can be inferred contextually that you are passing a template in all cases, so the disambiguator is useless unless you use template pointy brackets (which need to be disambiguated from less-than/greater-than operators). However, that "inferring from context" is not a feature in C++20, so we need `template` here.

Answer (score 2):

Visual studio is wrong and was always wrong with that type of code.

Take a look a `IIterableWith`:

```
template <typename ITERABLE, template <typename> typename ITEM_PREDICATE>
concept IIterableWith = ...
```

As you can see, the second parameter is a *template*, not a typename.

---

Now let's play a game. Do you think this should compile?

```
template <typename ITERABLE, typename OF_T>
concept IIterable = IIterableWith<ITERABLE, int>;
```

Now I bet you'll answer me no, because `int` is not a template itself.

Okay, one more step: what about this one?

```
template <typename ITERABLE, typename OF_T>
concept IIterable = IIterableWith<ITERABLE, OF_T>;
```

If you still answer me that it has to not compile, you'd be right! `OF_T` is not a template. But how do the compiler knows? The compiler don't even know what `OF_T` is in reality, it's still a template parameter to be filled.

Well, this is because the compiler still has to construct a partial AST during first phase name lookup of the template. Every template parameter has a *kind*. `OF_T` is a `typename`, so we know it cannot be a template or a value. It has to be a type. This is good! It means the compiler can validate if the code makes sense before instantiating the template.

Now let's go a step further, and add one more layer. Does this compile?

```
template <typename ITERABLE, typename OF_T>
concept IIterable = IIterableWith<ITERABLE, std::vector<OF_T>::value_type>;
```

No of course not! You have to tell what `value_type` is right? `value_type` has to be a type right? This is because the compiler assume a dependent name is a value and not a type. `::value_type` is assumed to be a type is this expression. Let's fix it:

```
template <typename ITERABLE, typename OF_T>
concept IIterable = IIterableWith<ITERABLE, typename std::vector<OF_T>::value_type>;
```

There you go! It still won't compile though.

But wait a sec! Why do we have to do that, why `value_type` was assumed to be a value and not a type?

This is because the compiler cannot know what is the content of `std::vector<OF_T>`. Depending of what `OF_T` is, `std::vector` could take in any specialization. You might imagine someone defining an instantiation with `static int value_type;`. The compiler cannot assume anything about the content because it is a *dependent type*. A type that depends on a template. A dependent type is just as unknown as the template parameter!

So on a dependent expression, like this one: `typename std::vector<OF_T>::value_type`, the only reason `value_type` is an actual type is because of `typename`.

All good now, let's try with your code:

```
template <typename ITERABLE, typename OF_T>
concept IIterable = IIterableWith<ITERABLE, typename IsAddableOfT<OF_T>::Test>;
```

So here you say that `::Test` must be a type, just like int.

In the eyes of the compiler, `Test` must be as much a type as `int` or `OF_T` since you explicitly say that you expect `::Test` to be a type.

Instead of saying it's a type, you have to instruct the compiler that `Test` is a template:

```
template <typename ITERABLE, typename OF_T>
concept IIterable = IIterableWith<ITERABLE, IsAddableOfT<OF_T>::template Test>;
```

Now it works! `IIterableWith` expects a template, and in this expression the compiler knows in advance that `Test` has to be a template too. It matches, it compiles.

Comment: THANK YOU for a GREAT response. My only disapointment with it is that there were TWO great answers and I have to pick between them. MOSTLY picking the other one cuz more succinct and to the point, and came first. But its a tough call. BOTH were great for different reasons.

Comment: I appreciate the (occasional) need for the compiler to insist on disambiguators. But its hard when different compilers have different requirements for these disambiguators, and equally challenging is how these requirements are RARELY explained well in error messages, and vary from version to version of the language (required in C++20 or you get misleading error message, and DEPRECATED in C++23).